# dependency error on libc6-amd64 even if it's already installed

Tags: apt, package-management, debian

Trying to install nodejs debian package that I built myself, i get error about missing: libc6-amd64 however, I am sure this lib is installed.

```
root@x72j:/home/reda/repo/git/node-debian# dpkg -i nodejs_5.0.0-1_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 151678 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack nodejs_5.0.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (5.0.0-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nodejs:
 nodejs depends on libc6-amd64 (>= 2.14).

dpkg: error processing package nodejs (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nodejs
```

and now the libc6-amd64:

```
root@x72j:/home/reda/repo/git/node-debian/nodejs-5.0.0/debian# apt-cache policy libc6-amd64
libc6-amd64:i386:
  Installed: 2.19-18+deb8u1
  Candidate: 2.19-18+deb8u1
  Version table:
 *** 2.19-18+deb8u1 0
        500 http://debian.ens-cachan.fr/ftp/debian/ jessie/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

What' could be the problem?

Comment: why down vote, please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solutions

I had to remove all i386 package i have installed, build again my .deb and install it.

```
root@x72j:/home/reda/repo/git/node-debian# dpkg -l | grep i386
ii  gcc-4.9-base:i386                     4.9.2-10                             i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libc6:i386                            2.19-18+deb8u1                       i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-amd64                           2.19-18+deb8u1                       i386         GNU C Library: 64bit Shared libraries for AMD64
ii  libc6-i386                            2.19-18+deb8u1                       amd64        GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64
ii  libc6-i686:i386                       2.19-18+deb8u1                       i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries [i686 optimized]
ii  libgcc1:i386                          1:4.9.2-10                           i386         GCC support library

root@x72j:/home/reda/repo/git/node-debian# 
apt-get remove --purge gcc-4.9-base:i386
apt-get remove --purge libc6-i386
```

Comment: How did you determine that the `i386` packages were the cause?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem due to a broken upgrade of PopOS. I tried the solutions above but did not work. I solved it using some of the suggestions in [this page](http://knoppix.net/forum/threads/29465-dpkg-error-upgr-libc6-A-copy-of...?p=124943)

First `sudo -i` and then reinstall `libc6:amd64` by doing:

```
dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_x.xx-0ubuntux_amd64.deb
```

replace `x` with the correct version.

Then I was able to run `apt --fix-broken install && apt update && apt upgrade`